# How do I check if a Linq to SQL entity has grandchildren?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How can I find out if a Linq to SQL entity has grandchildren or not?

Pseudo-code below:

```
Return From p In dc.Processes Where p.Signers.Count > 0 and p.Signers.Signatures.Count > 0
```

Obviously I can't run the code above but I need to make sure that all the returning Processes have at least one Signer and that all of those Signers have at least one Signature.

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

**... VB.Net ...**

```
Return From p In dc.Processes _
       Where p.Signers.Any(Function(s) s.Signatures.Any()) _
       Select p
```

... C# ...

```
return  from p in dc.Processes
        where p.Signers.Any(s=>s.Signatures.Any())
        select p;
```

Comment: I haven't done much with LINQ in VB so this might need a few minor tweaks.

Comment: oh that was just sweet and too simple for me not to realize on my own! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may have to do a sub select if your tables are many to many relationship.  Something like this should work in this instance

```
Return (From p In dc.Processes Where p.Signers.Count > 0 And (from t in p.Signers where t.signatures.count) > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is C#, but it will do the trick:

```
 from p in db.Processes
 where p.Signers.Any(s => s.Signatures.Any())
 select p
```